# weinre debugger server reporting invocation exception

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, weinre

I'm using WEINRE to debug/inspect a Cordova/Ionic app on Windows Phone 8 emulator (versions below).

When I run the WEINRE server, it works fine and I can inspect the app OK but the terminal where I started the server is logging around 100 errors per second that mostly look like this:

```
weinre: invocation exception on Object.attributesUpdated(): TypeError: Cannot read property '_setAttributesPayload' of undefined
```

The bigger the page view, the more errors occur. It seems to be related to the amount of tags on the page which makes sense considering the errors are to do with attributes and child nodes etc. Perhaps this is actually the DOM inspector that's causing it?

**Does anyone know what is causing this error, and how I can stop it?**

Here's the output from *weinre -v*:

```
version:    2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV
node versions:
http_parser : 2.5.2
node        : 4.4.3
v8          : 4.5.103.35
uv          : 1.8.0
zlib        : 1.2.8
ares        : 1.10.1-DEV
icu         : 56.1
modules     : 46
openssl     : 1.0.2g
```

Other versions

- Ionic 1.7.4
- Cordova 6.1.1
- WP 8 WVGA 512mb emulator
- Visual studio 2015
- Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the messages are being generated from [this code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre/blob/cc97191c79ca260b5bbf83b19d5cfc3e02468cac/weinre.web/modules/weinre/target/NodeStore.coffee#L225), which indicates some of the initialization of weinre didn't complete successfully.  Were there any messages you saw before this one, or any known errors that occurred while your web page was loading?

Comment: No, that was the first message in the terminal after starting weinre and running the app. Thanks for pointing me at the code, I had a look and for now, have suppressed the error by checking for an undefined value of 'node' at [this line](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre/blob/cc97191c79ca260b5bbf83b19d5cfc3e02468cac/weinre.build/vendor/webkit/WebCore/inspector/front-end/DOMAgent.js#L357) but it's not the only occurrence of looking for properties of undefined objects. Presumably there's a root cause though and those checks shoudln't be required?

Comment: yes, there seems to be a root cause of the `Weinre.wi.DOMNotify` object not getting set up.  This is done at initialization time, so this kind of thing can occur if some kind of exception is thrown during initialization, in [this code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre/blob/cc97191c79ca260b5bbf83b19d5cfc3e02468cac/weinre.web/modules/weinre/target/Target.coffee#L153).  Likely lots of stuff won't work, because probably all of those `Weinre.wi` properties were not initialized.